# Java "jsonify" simple string ("äh" -> "\u00e4h")

Tags: java, android, json, string

In Python I can execute the following

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
print json.dumps("äh")
```

In PHP I can execute

```
json_encode('äh')
```

which both results in `"\u00e4h"`

How can I do the same in Java? I tried using `JSONObject`, but it only accepts JSON strings that already contain key-values.

Comment: Consider using `Gson` a library from google

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON utilities to print UTF-8 code points is a bit overkill in Java.

In Java8 use `IntStream String.codePoints()`:

```
String text = "äh";
text.codePoints().forEach(c -> System.out.print("\\u" + String.format("%04Xh ", c)));
```

In earlier Java versions (including **Android SDK**):

```
String text = "äh";
for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print("\\u" + String.format("%04Xh ", text.codePointAt(i)));
}
```

Both result in:

```
\u00E4h \u0068h
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that this is on Android, so no Java 8

Comment: Where is this `\u0068h` coming from?

Comment: The `h` at the end of `\u00E4h` is the `h` that is the second character in `äh` It doesn't need to be encoded to be JSON compilant.

Comment: there are two letters in the string being converted - each returns its code point

Comment: I'm rejecting the title change because the JSON part is important.

Comment: ok, this is going to be a philosophical debate.. "äh" is also correct within JSON standard as per RFC: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt   
"All Unicode characters may be placed within the
   quotation marks except for the characters that must be escaped:
   quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000
   through U+001F)." Initially I have thought all you want is to print utf-8 code points of a given string using JSON tools; Now I understand that you are attempting to send JSON somewhere... is the literal text not working for you?

Comment: using the above method to encode specifically for JSON will break as this is literal character by character encoder and would simply thrash over any escaped characters like `\b`, `\t` etc therefore we are back at JSONifying - sorry @DanielF, I will resurrect this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145183/discussion-between-daniel-f-and-diginoise).

Answer (score 0):

For JSON, you need to escape certain characters to unicode escape sequences (`\u1234`). In most Java JSON libraries this is done like this (taken from [here](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/simple/JSONValue.java)):

```
/**
 * Escape quotes, \, /, \r, \n, \b, \f, \t and other control characters (U+0000 through U+001F).
 * @param s
 * @return
 */
public static String escape(String s){
    if(s==null)
        return null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    escape(s, sb);
    return sb.toString();
}

/**
 * @param s - Must not be null.
 * @param sb
 */
static void escape(String s, StringBuffer sb) {
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        char ch=s.charAt(i);
        switch(ch){
        case '"':
            sb.append("\\\"");
            break;
        case '\\':
            sb.append("\\\\");
            break;
        case '\b':
            sb.append("\\b");
            break;
        case '\f':
            sb.append("\\f");
            break;
        case '\n':
            sb.append("\\n");
            break;
        case '\r':
            sb.append("\\r");
            break;
        case '\t':
            sb.append("\\t");
            break;
        case '/':
            sb.append("\\/");
            break;
        default:
            //Reference: http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.1.0/
            if((ch>='\u0000' && ch<='\u001F') || (ch>='\u007F' && ch<='\u009F') || (ch>='\u2000' && ch<='\u20FF')){
                String ss=Integer.toHexString(ch);
                sb.append("\\u");
                for(int k=0;k<4-ss.length();k++){
                    sb.append('0');
                }
                sb.append(ss.toUpperCase());
            }
            else{
                sb.append(ch);
            }
        }
    }//for
}
```

As far as I can tell the methods above will not escape your `ä` character—because it does not need to be escaped, as long as you are using UTF-8 as encoding for the resulting JSON text, which I guess you want to send somewhere.

So either, use UTF-8 as your content-encoding and don't escape `ä` (not needed), or modify the method above to escape everything with `ch > 127`. I.e.:

```
[...]
        default:
            //Reference: http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.1.0/
            if((ch > 127) || (ch>='\u0000' && ch<='\u001F') || (ch>='\u007F' && ch<='\u009F') || (ch>='\u2000' && ch<='\u20FF')){
                String ss=Integer.toHexString(ch);
                sb.append("\\u");
                for(int k=0;k<4-ss.length();k++){
                    sb.append('0');
                }
                sb.append(ss.toUpperCase());
            }
            else{
                sb.append(ch);
            }
[...]
```

And then it should work...